# To break down a problem

Tags: single-word-requests

There exists a problem or goal which cannot be achieved in one action, therefore one breaks the problem into smaller problems and solves each to ultimately reach the goal.

In one word, what verb is one doing to the problem?

Comment: Why does everybody think that anything you do should be describable in one word?

Comment: reduces the problem

Comment: @DJClayworth because it's part of a bullet list

Comment: @stevemarvell Style over substance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called problem **decomposition** or **decomposing** a problem. According to [State Uni. Of New York](http://www.cs.oswego.edu/~blue/xhx/books/csjs/cs/problemsolvingpatterns/section01/main.html)

> Problem decomposition is the problem solving strategy of breaking a problem up into a set of subproblems, solving each of the subproblems, and then composing a solution to the original problem from the solutions to the subproblems.

Definition of decompose according to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decomposition)  is:

> to separate into constituent parts or elements or into simpler compounds

Comment: It might be possible to misunderstand this without using it in a sentence.

Comment: Using the phrase **Problem decomposition** is enough to convey the intended meaning i.e. breaking down the problem into subproblem, and solving each of the subproblems, and then composing a solution to the original problem.

Comment: It's still hard to get away from compost heaps

Comment: @stevemarvell ha! It is a very common terminology used in sciences, arts, technology, mathematics, analysis, reasoning, logic, statistics etc.

Comment: But not members of the public

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're *breaking down* the problem, but if you need one word, I'd go with *dissect*:

> 1: to separate into pieces
>   : expose the several parts of (something, such as an animal) for scientific examination
>   // dissect an earthworm
>   // dissecting flowers
>   2: to analyze and interpret minutely
>   // dissect a problem

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dissect#synonyms))

You see how the first (literal, and probably older) definition leads to the second (figurative) definition.

Answer (score 1):

'Break down' is a perfectly good verb and usable in virtually any circumstances.

If you absolutely insist on describing this in one word, then 'split' would work. Also 'break', which you used in the question. Other synonyms are 'divide', 'separate', 'subdivide', 'dissociate' 'segment'.

Closely related are 'sever', 'dissever', 'section', and a pile of others.